# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- EventService?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm testing an ionic app created using creator.

I put the following code in `services.js`.

angular.module('app.services', [])

```
.factory('BlankFactory', [function(){
}])
.factory('EventService', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('https://.....net/api/events/:id');
}])
.service('BlankService', [function(){
}]);
```

And the following code in `controllers.js`.

```
angular.module('app.controllers', [])
......
  .controller('nightlifeCtrl', function ($scope, EventService) {
    $scope.events = EventsService.query({category: "Nightlife"});
})
```

Hoever I got the following error in js console?

```
ionic.bundle.js:25642 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $resourceProvider <- $resource <- EventService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24resourceProvider%20%3C-%20%24resource%20%3C-%20EventService
    at ionic.bundle.js:13380
    at ionic.bundle.js:17574
    at Object.getService [as get] (ionic.bundle.js:17721)
    at ionic.bundle.js:17579
    at getService (ionic.bundle.js:17721)
    at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:17753)
    at Object.enforcedReturnValue [as $get] (ionic.bundle.js:17615)
    at Object.invoke (ionic.bundle.js:17762)
    at ionic.bundle.js:17580
    at getService (ionic.bundle.js:17721)
```

I tried to add the dependency by `angular.module('...', ['ngResource'])` but it got the following error.

```
ionic.bundle.js:17697 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.controllers due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngResource due to:
```

And I didn't find the file `angular-resource.js` in the js files. Should I avoid ngResource and use plain ajax call?

In `index.html`

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/routes.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not working because you have not loaded the `angular-resource` dependency. If you want to use an external module in angular, you need to load it as a dependency in your module definition by passing name of the module in the second array parameter to `angular.module`. In your case name of the module is `ngResource`. Load the script file for `angular-resource.js` and then add it as dependency as below:

```
angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource'])
```

Also I see that you have not loaded `app.services` as dependency in `app.controller`. You need to either load that dependency or load both these dependencies in your app definition module as:

```
angular.module('app', [
  'app.services',
  'app.controllers'
]);
```

Updated [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/bimugop/edit?html,js,console,output) with fix for console error

Your code also had one typo. You were referring to `EventsService` in your controller while the name was `EventService`. I have fixed that as well in the jsbin

Comment: The following code was found in app.js `angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers', 'app.routes', 'app.services', 'app.directives'])`. However, it seems the default ionic doesn't have the angular-resource.js?

Comment: Ionic bundle does not have `angular-resource`. It just has `angular` and 'angular-ui/ui-router`. So you need to add that dependency explicitly. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Can I just copy another version of angular-resource.js to the ionic js folder?

Comment: No not like that. Let me create a jsbin for you

Comment: I have updated the above with JSbin. Take a look now and accept if it solves your issue :)

Comment: It got the following error `ionic.bundle.js:25642 ReferenceError: EventsService is not defined
    at new <anonymous> (controllers.js:40)
    at invoke (ionic.bundle.js:17762)`

Comment: If you see my JSBin and comment I have mentioned that it was a typo in your code.

Comment: You are right (bad part dynamic language). It works! I just add one reference and use the same original local js files `<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-resource.min.js'></script>` though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109304/discussion-between-aditya-singh-and-dc7a9163d9).